# Gstreamer RTSP webcam server

Tags: gstreamer

I want to read the feed from a webcam and host a RTSP stream without encoding the feed. I have access to high bandwidth network but the CPUs are very low end and have other tasks to full fill due to which I want to skip the encoding/decoding steps to save up on CPU usage. Before jumping on to RTSP I tried a simple MJPG stream and tried to skip the `jpegenc` (JPG encoding) as it can be done directly with a simple gst pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=800,height=600,framerate=25/1 ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=10.0.1.10 port=5000
```

However, I got a warning:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link videoscale0 to
>   rtpjpegpay0, rtpjpegpay0 can't handle caps video/x-raw,
>   format=(string)I420, width=(int)800, height=(int)600,
>   framerate=(fraction)25/1

I'm new to Gstreamer and not sure if this is possible and how to move forward next. The same command above works if I include the jpg encoding. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this helping you: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpvrawpay.html?gi-language=c#rtpvrawpay
RFC 4175 is raw video at RTP (and so at RTSP).

Answer (score 0):

`rtpjpegpay` is an element that takes in a Motion JPEG stream and translates it to RTP. The input you're giving it however is`video/x-raw`, which means it is *unencoded*, rather than encoded with Motion JPEG. If you want to use this element, you'll first have to encode it to Motion JPEG, using something like [`jpegenc`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/jpeg/jpegenc.html?gi-language=c).

Like @vermaete already mentions: if you really, really don't want to encode your video, you can use someting like [`rtpvrawpay`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpvrawpay.html?gi-language=c#rtpvrawpay), which will translate your raw video into RTP packets. However: sending raw, unencoded video over the network is not really advisable (and not even workable if you have a bad connection, or even impossible if you plan on sending it over the Internet). You might also end up using a lot of resources on your CPU just to get everything payloaded properly, and gettign it sent to your network card.

Comment: I did use `rtpvrawpay` and it seemed to do the job, I got the cpu usage down from 30% to 10%. So my pipeline is : `gst-launch-1.0 -v autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=800,height=600,framerate=25/1 ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host=10.0.1.13 port=5000`. Now I want to do this in rtsp so that I can just have url to access at the client. How can I do this?